# Displaytag in struts2 checked columns dissappear when changing pages

Tags: struts2, displaytag, checked

i have this problem with displaytag...when i check some rows in the table and after go in another page for checking others the checked elements of the previous page disappear.
If i return to the previous page all the rows are unchecked...this is my code:

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" %>
 …

<s:form action="actionSample" theme="simple">
     <display:table
         id="row"
                name="tableSample"
                requestURI="/sample"  
                sort="list"
                pagesize="10"
                cellpadding="0"
                cellspacing="0"

                >

        <display:column property="one" title="ONE" sortable="true"   />
        <display:column property="two" title="TWO" sortable="true"  />
        <display:column headerClass="sortheader" title="SELECTION" style="text-align:center;">
            <s:checkbox theme="simple" name="check" fieldValue='%{#attr.row.idOne}' />
        </display:column>

      </display:table>
    <div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div align="right">
        <s:submit type="button" label="SUBMIT"/>
    </div>
```

How can i resolve this problem?, thank you for the answer...

P.S. i omitted the code of the action class, there is an array of string named "check" that stores the ids of the element selected

Comment: Keep the values of the modified checkboxes in the session and substitute it instead of actual values while navigating the pages or submit the page before each move, so the values would be already updated when you move back.